# Execute a command using php under ssh2 in php

Tags: php, ssh, exec

Using Mint terminal my script connects using ssh2_connect and ssh2_auth-password. 
When am logged in successfully I want to run a command which will give me the hardware cpu. Is there a way I can use to exec the command in my script then show the results. I have used system and exec for pinging. if i was in the terminal i do the login. then type "get hardware cpu"

in the terminal it would look like this:

Test~ $ get hardware cpu

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`ssh2_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php)? There is a [comment on that page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#99089) that seems to do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need access to the shell:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($ip, $port);
$stream = ssh2_shell($connection);
fputs($stream, $input);
$buffer = fread($stream, 8192);
```

Have a look at this example:

```
$input = "ls\nexit\n";
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass);
$stream = ssh2_shell($connection);
stream_set_blocking($stream, 1);
stream_set_timeout($stream, 2);
fputs($stream, $input);

while (!feof($stream)) {
        echo $buffer = fread($stream, $buffersize);
}
```

You might have to `sleep()` and `fread()` manually since people experience problems when setting the ssh2 stream blocking.

Comment: I have tried want to show the result cause when I put in get hardware cpu in the terminal after I have done my ssh2 authintication it works in the terminal want to put this command and run in my php script.

Comment: Here is my script:
<?php 
$connection = ssh2_connect('100.168.0.3', 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)) {
echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
$stream = ssh2_shell($connection);
$input ='get hardware cpu';
fputs($stream, $input);
$buffer = fread($stream, 8192);
echo $buffer;
}
else
{
echo "Authentication unsuccessful!\n";
}
?>

Comment: Resource id#5 that is what i get when I run my php file

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (requires [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec("grep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where this "get hardware" command comes from. If you're trying to figure out what cpu is powering the system, then

```
grep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo
```

will output the ID string of the cpu:

```
marc@panic:~$ grep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6600  @ 2.40GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6600  @ 2.40GHz
```

Comment: You'd need to run it on the terminal via SSH - not via SCP. But you're in luck - if you can do SCP that means you have SSH terminal access as SCP runs through the terminal.